# Verifying behavior when testing a method that throws an exception

Tags: java, junit, jmockit

Recently, in a code review, a colleague said "Tests should not have try-catch blocks".  He also pointed me to information about [`ExpectedException`](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html), and I was able to use it to rewrite some of my tests that were performing checks on the exception data.

However, I'm encountering a situation where I'm not sure I can eliminate the try-catch.  I'm writing a unit test for a method that will throw an exception **and** that will perform some behavior that I need to verify using JMockit.  Suppose the code under test contains something like

```
try {
    ...code...
} catch (SomeException e) {
    statusMessage.send("Failure", <parameters with some data>);
    throw e;
}
```

The JUnit test currently looks like

```
@Test
public void test() {
    ... set things up ...
    try {
        callTheMethod();
        fail("No exception thrown");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        assertEquals(SomeException.class, e.getClass());
    }
    new Verifications() { {
        statusMessage.send("Failure", <expected data>);
    } }
}
```

I can't find a good way to get rid of the try-catch.  I don't see a problem with having it there, personally, but if I don't at least *try* to get rid of it I'm likely to *catch* heck from my colleague :) :) :)

The `fail` and `assertEquals` aren't necessary.  If there's a simple way to tell JUnit/JMockit to simply ignore any exception from `callTheMethod()` and continue, that would be fine--I can create another test to check the exception.

Is there some JUnit or JMockit feature that would let me accomplish what I'm trying to do?

[Note: Edited to make it clear that the behavior I'm testing is a call on a mocked object, not a static method call.  It really isn't relevant to the question.]

Comment: It's stupid to make a blanket statement that tests should not have try-catch blocks. Rather, tests should not catch exceptions unless that specific exception is expected as part of that test.

Comment: @gknicker You could have stopped your comment after the first seven words.

Comment: Maybe some middleground: instead of `assertEquals(..` you could potentially put the `new Verification` part into the catch block and then `throw e` afterwards. Wouldn't bother personally because you're not only interested in the exception but also what happens in between and that's simply not the standard "exception expected" test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your colleague may be right in the general sense, using `try-catch` to test your exception handling is less desirable than using the provided `ExpectedException` utilities. However, I don't think that rule applies to your case; catching the exception so you can verify other things is perfectly reasonable. There's no other way to stop an exception from from propagating, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Currently with plain JUnit you have to use `try-catch` if you want to verify something after the assertion is thrown. With JUnit 4.13 (not released yet) you can use

```
expectThrows(Exception.class, () -> callTheMethod());
new Verifications() { {
    statusMessage.send("Failure", <expected data>);
} }
```

As an alternative you can use the [Fishbowl's ignoreException](http://stefanbirkner.github.io/fishbowl/).

```
ignoreException(() -> callTheMethod());
new Verifications() { {
    statusMessage.send("Failure", <expected data>);
} }
```

Full disclosure: I'm the author of Fishbowl.

Comment: Cool!  That will be useful.  Don't think we have Fishbowl available for production use, so I'll look forward to 4.13 coming out.

Comment: You can simply copy the `ignoreException` method from Fishbowl if you don't have Fishbowl available.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the [API](http://junit.org/apidocs/org/junit/rules/ExpectedException.html), I'd say you could do something like:

```
class AjbUnitTest
{
    @Rule 
    public ExpectedException thrown = ExpectedException.none();

    @Test
    public void test()
    {
        ... set things up ...
        thrown.expect(SomeException.class)
        callTheMethod();  / Preumably this throws SomeException
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: But when `callTheMethod()` throws the exception, it's all over for the test.  If there are `Verifications` following that line, they won't get checked.  I believe I already tested this, and that's the behavior I observed.

Comment: Oh okay. If you need to keep going, then you need the `try .. catch`. I think the rule is sensible, but rules can be broken if warranted. I think this is such a situation.

Answer (score -2):

For exception specific assertions [AssertJ](http://joel-costigliola.github.io/assertj) has a good API:

```
@Test
public void testException() {
   assertThatThrownBy(() -> { throw new Exception("error!") })
     .isInstanceOf(Exception.class)
     .hasMessageContaining("error");
}
```

Basically, you can "collect" the exception without disrupting the test execution.

Comment: While you're probably right about the `StatusMessage` (and I did use a mock in the real code, I was just trying to throw a simplified example together quickly), this in no way answers the question.

Comment: @ajb Code provided in question, is assumed to be part of the question.

Comment: I think it's pretty well established on SO that if you want to say something about a questioner's code that doesn't relate to the question they asked, it should be a comment and not a separate answer.